# Не работает стиль для мобильного приложения

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Есть форма поиска. для мониторов с компьютера она должна отображаться с правой стороны. Для мобильных устройств - с левой. но через мобильный браузер форма поиска все равно располагается с права.

```css
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .search {
    float: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="search" style="float:right;">
  <form action="" method="post" class="search">
    <input type="search" name="" placeholder="поиск" class="input" />
    <input type="submit" name="" value="" class="submit" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Приведите ваш полный отображающий проблему [mcve], в чем у вас возникла сложность? То что видно, у вас просто не доделано, или вы хотите, чтобы доделали за вас?

Comment: учите flex-box.. float-ы создают огромное количество проблем

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего проблема в приоритете. Стили указаны в атрибуте `style` являются самыми приоритетными.

**У Вас есть два варианта:**
1. Использовать стили исключительно в файлике css (без атрибута)(Рекомендую);
2. Поставить флаг важности

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .search {
    float: left !important;
  }
}
```